# Inconsistent race times on a completely straight track

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D topdown racing game which measures the time it takes the player to finish a track and I noticed that even on a completely straight track, the finish times are not always the same (the car accelerates automatically).

I've tried setting both the Maximum allowed timestep and Fixed Timestep to the same value (both are 0.02), not sure if that has any impact on this.

For the timer I use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` which starts in the `Start()` method

```
void Start()
    {
        checkpoints = GetComponentsInChildren<Checkpoint>();
        sw.Start(); //stopwatch starts
        Load();
        checkpointsReached = 1;
        nextCheckpoint = checkpoints[checkpointsReached];
    }
```

and stops when the car touches a trigger marked as finish.

```
internal void CheckpointReached(Checkpoint checkpoint)
    {
        if (nextCheckpoint != checkpoint)
            return;

        checkpointsReached++;

        if (checkpoint.isFinish)
        {
            sw.Stop();  //stopwatch stops after reaching Finish
            EndRace();
            return;
        }

        if (checkpointsReached == checkpoints.Length)
        {
            checkpointsReached = 0;
        }

        nextCheckpoint = checkpoints[checkpointsReached];
    }
```

To get the race time I use `sw.Elapsed.ToString("ss','ffff");`

The car acceleration is done in another script

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * speedForce);  //acceleration


        //turning and stuff
        rb.angularVelocity = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * torqueForce;
        rb.velocity = ForwardVelocity() + RightVelocity() * driftFactor;
```

I want the game to be consistent and fair so I expect the finish time on a straight road to be always the same, but right now the times are in range of +/- 0.02s from each other.

Comment: You need to multiply your forces, physics, forward motion etc by time.delta time to make it consistent with different frame rates

Comment: Sometimes it's important to keep in mind that games operate on hardware and firmware which has limitations. There is no such thing as perfect. I think 20ms is a perfectly acceptable margin of error.

Comment: @theMayer but there are some speedrun games that measure up to milliseconds and they need the precision. But maybe they're not made in Unity...?

Answer (score 3):

Stopwatch is a very precise time measurement device, and 0.02s equals one frame if you are pushing 50 FPS. Unity's time system is discrete, and increments only when the new frame (or physics frame) starts, so nothing 'moves in the background', you cannot expect accuracy higher than frame - there is no sub-frame times in Unity.

Please note that if you measure using stopwatch, you are measuring hard realtime, which means that if your game freezes for a split second, it will add to the stopwatch time, but will not add to the game time. Generally you should be using UnityEngine.Time.time to measure game time, stopwatch is generally used for performance diganostics (thats why its under System.Diagnostics namespace), not for business logic.

Also, humans cannot 'see' a 0.02s difference under normal conditions.

Comment: the thing with Time.time that I noticed is that it always saved only even numbers, like 15.22, 15.24, 15.26 etc. which is not realistic

Comment: @otset, you should really read up on statistical process control

Comment: I agree with zambari. One way to take this even further would be to have the calculated time ticking in a manager, so all cars go off of that standardized time then get the start time when they finish. This eliminates any time delays or inconsistencies in the amount of ms it takes to spawn one car and run its initialization functions for each car.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Time.time` if you want consistent duration, it's always a multiple of `Time.fixedDeltaTime` in `FixedUpdate` event. If you want more precision, decrease that value.